# In Tridion 5.3 if we use unique Content Delivery instances can we configure different binding targets on a per publication basis?

Tags: content-delivery, broker, 5.3

We are using Tridion 5.3 and are wondering if we use unique Content Delivery instances can we specify different binding targets for the broker depending on the target publication.

We want to use the SQL binding for some publications and the file system binding for others.

Is this approach viable?

Comment: Tfinez, welcome to the Tridion Stack Exchange! I have edited your question title and description to hopefully clarify your question some. If you think I mischaracterized your intentions please let me know and feel free to revert the changes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In R5.3, you cannot set bindings differently per publication in the same configuration file. As Pankaj pointed out you can set both file system and database bindings for the same publication BUT from the same configuration you cannot vary the bindings for different sites.

If you want to do this, you'll need different CD instances with their own configuration file. For deployment you can use deployer instances and for delivery you can have separate websites each with their own configuration.

SDL Tridion 2011 and above supports different bindings per publication in the same configuration file.

Comment: So Julian, is it the case in this situation tfinez would need just two CD instance? One for the publications which will be bound to SQL and another for the ones which will be bound to the file system? Or does tfinez have to go as far as setting up a CD instance for each publication?

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can manage that through your **cd_broker_conf.xml** by assigning appropriate binding. Please take note of the following from the R5.3 SP1 manual regarding what all you can store on FS and what all you can store on DB:

[image]

For further details, I would recommend you to go thorugh the Content Delivery Implementation Guide that you can download from SDL Tridion World.

May be if you can zero down your requirement and paste your Broker Configuration File, the community can better help you :)

By the way, you can add another `Publication` node in the Parent `Publications` node with its id and defining Defaults Binding and even specific bindings for items in this publication.